# Compression On the Server, JavaScript lz-string decompression on the Client

Tags: javascript

At the moment, my app is making an AJAX call to a C# method that returns a JSONResult of about 600K. I then compress this using [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) and save it to session storage. To improve efficiency, I'm thinking of compressing this data on the server and sending a compressed copy to the browser. There are lots of C# tools I can use to compress data. However, I need to compress this in such a way that lz-string can decompress it on the client. Has anyone done something like this? If so, how?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [compress-decompress-string-on-net-server-that-was-encoded-with-lz-string-js-on][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512386/compress-decompress-string-on-net-server-that-was-encoded-with-lz-string-js-on/28893729#28893729

Comment: @Richard - This is part of the problem with SO. People like you take no time to determine if the question is a duplicate, and if so, has it been answered. I don't suppose you took the time to read the 'duplicate' question and answer provided. The answer was no answer at all and certainly doesn't provide a solution to my question or the 'duplicate' question.

Comment: Please read the question again. It asks exactly what you are asking - if this can be done in C# and Javascript. It can. I answered the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512386/compress-decompress-string-on-net-server-that-was-encoded-with-lz-string-js-on/28893729#28893729